# converting RDD to xml in pyspark without databricks

Tags: xml, hadoop, pyspark

Is there a way to convert a csv to XMl using pyspark without using the databricks library?

coctails csv:

```
cocktail_name,cocktail_base,ingredients,portions in oz,garnish
last word,gin,chartreuse&maraschino&lime,2&3/4th&3/4th&3/4th,cherry
whiskey sour,whiskey,lemon juice&simple syrp,2&3/4&1/2,bitters
```

I have the python code for this but now I have to put it in our hadoop environment, and convert to xml. Every example I've seen is using databricks.xml and I don't have that option right now.

Comment: You mean `spark-xml`? https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml if you can't add packages, then how are you getting other dependencies?

Comment: Assuming your file is small, then use your existing python code, then parallelize the result to get it into a Spark object. Alternatively, reconsider your need for XML because most Hadoop native tooling does not prefer it